# How can I detect an error when creating a thread in swift?

Tags: swift

How can I catch an error when creating a thread? I tried doing it like this but It hasn't worked. It says that catch is unreachable. Do I just check if the thread is executing?

```
@objc func threadmain(){
    do{
         /*Doing something*/
    }
    catch{
          print("More errors here")
    }
}
func this(){
    do{
        myThread = Thread (target: self, selector: #selector(threadmain), object: nil)
        try myThread.start()
    } catch {
        print("There was an error with mythread")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing inside

```
myThread.start()
```

That throws an error , so you can't do/catch it , this over testing isn't needed anymore  , BTW use `myThread.isExecuting` right below the start line

Comment: I was thinking to add that line too. I just wasn't sure. Thanks